# How to format an array of hashes correctly for a morris chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, morris.js

I'm trying to reproduce the following array to be used in a morris.js chart:

```
{month:"02/2014", 'Fred':3, 'Glen':4, 'Thomas':5}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
def self.chart_data(business)
 Positions.group_by(&:month).map  do |month, data|
 hash = {month: month.strftime("%m/%Y")}
 data.each {|pos| hash[pos.employee.name] = pos.position}
 hash
end
```

It produces the following array which doesn't seem to work with the morris.js jquery

```
{:month=>"02/2014", 'Fred'=>3, :'Glen'=>4, :'Thomas'=>5}
```

Any ideas on how to format the array correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse it to json:

```
{:month=>"02/2014", 'Fred'=>3, :'Glen'=>4, :'Thomas'=>5}.to_json

 => "{\"month\":\"02/2014\",\"Fred\":3,\"Glen\":4,\"Thomas\":5}"
```

Comment: That doesn't give the exact same result though?